# How to get drawable Id in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to get drawable Id in Android Studio quickly. 
I know that I can use **Resources** class method:

```
public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

But is it possible to get drawable Id without coding if I only want to hardcode this id somewhere or put it to database?

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what the method does. As long as you have the name, the number itself can vary. If you have a `<string name="someString>...</...>`, `getIdentifier("someString", "string", "com.my.package")` returns the resource ID. You really shouldn't hard-code the ID... Just rely on the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend you think about saving the id to a database or hardcoding it. The ID may change after compilation.